# get start with file uploading from mobile to computer with Google app engine

Tags: android, google-app-engine

I designed to write a mobile application which can upload/download files from mobile devices to computer, to provide something like backup service provided by cloud.

While I do not know how to get started, someone suggested me to use Google app engine and I have visited the sites for more information, but I only find that files will be uploaded to Google cloud, instead of to a computer. Do I miss anything in the site?

What I want to do are:

1. I would like to code with Java and on Android platform.
2. Use mobile application to choose file for uploading.
3. The file will be upload to a computer (serve as a server for storing data)
4. File can be download back to the mobile devices.

Will Google app engine help me to complete this task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like Selvin said...  How to get started is the [Java Tutorial](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/gettingstarted/introduction) and [Google Cloud Endpoints](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/).  What you were missing is that your Android software (or other computers) can request downloads and save the results to achieve the restore function.

"Complete this task" looks like a homework assignment. Know that StackOverflow rules and users are opposed to "do my work for me" type of questions.  The more you can show that your have tried to write the software yourself, the more people here will be willing to help.